# PSQL console encoding

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql, encoding, utf-8

How can I have a working PSQL console using UTF8 encoding under Windows?

I have a Windows server and client. The Postgres 12 database contains tables with content in multiple languages (ex: English, French (with characters such as `é`), Korean (with characters such as `브`)).

The DB is encoded as UTF8.

The `client_encoding` is set to `UTF8`.

The console code page is set to 65001 (Microsoft's UTF8 [codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)), and has a suitable font (
Lucida Console)

I must be able to properly display English and French text, query the DB in English and French and be able to "output something", i.e. not get any error, if touching text in another language.

The issue is I can't type / copy-paste any accented character. If I do, the special character acts as a comment but the input continues on the next line, and I need to close it again.

In the following example, note that `é_fg` is gone, that there is no prompt on the `hij` line and that the output concatenates `abcd_hij` on one line

```
myuser=> select 'abcd_é_fg';
hij
myuser'> klm';
 ?column?
----------
 abcd_hij+
 klm
(1 row)
```

The issue is really with the typing, because I can export and load files containing such chars.

Ex: save `select 'é';` in `sel.sql`, run `psql -U myuser -d mydb -f C:/sel.sql`

will output

```
 ?column?
----------
 é
```

---

On the working well side, I can display what I need

```
select chr(8217); --sort of apostrophe
 chr
-----
 ’

select chr(48652);
 chr
-----
 브 --(though displayed as a square - unknown character, ok)
```

---

I have tried to set Windows language for non-Unicode program to UTF8, which had no effect on the issue.

If I set the code page to 1252 and the client-encoding to Win1252, I can display the accented chars, I can type them, but if I want to display text in another language like Korean I get and error

```
select chr(48652);
```

> ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xeb 0xb8 0x8c in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"

Comment: Did you try using the "Lucida Console" font and running `chcp 65001`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, both are set

Comment: Then probably not. Blame Microsoft. You'll have to use a different client software (or use `psql` on a different operating system).

Comment: I’d also ask the Postgres developers if this is a known issue and not actually a bug. Blaming Microsoft is what we often do, but they might not actually be at fault here.

Comment: Other clients, such as DBeaver, works fine. Good idea @Colin'tHart, I will ask the mailing list

Comment: But DBeaver is not a console app, right?

Comment: :-) not exactly

Comment: @Colin'tHart I agree in principle, but this is obviously due to `cmd.exe`'s known inability to handle UTF-8.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - So the lucky Chinese don't have to use a DOS programme?

Comment: The issue is not so much to be able to use 1 language but multiple ones, making local code page unable to cover all the characters

Comment: just to follow up, I got no feedback from the mailing list.